# Pig Multi-Query Optimization issue

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

We are running into issues on Pig's Multiquery Optimizer does not work as expected.

As I understood, the below script should be run as one MR job, but it runs as two jobs on our cluster. I think the Multiquery Optimization should be on by default, am I missing anything here? If I replace the group by by "filter" statement then it works as one single MR job.

```
data = LOAD 'input' AS (a:chararray, b:int, c:int);
A = GROUP data BY b;
B = GROUP data BY c;
STORE A INTO 'output1';
STORE B INTO 'output2';
```

I'm using CDH packed pig 0.1.0 and Hadoop 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

If 0.1.0 is the real version of your pig installation - it's very OLD. The latest version is 0.11.1.

Page about performance from 0.11.1 docs:
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/perf.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Multiquery Optimization would take effort here, multiquery optimization usually is for split. In your example, there're 2 group by, must cause 2 kinds of shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

In Pig, every GROUP BY requires a MR shuffle. And MR shuffles data based on a key. A single MR job cannot shuffle data two ways (based on two different keys). The script is doing two GROUP BY operations, which will hence result in two MR jobs. So Pig will not be able to do [multi-query optimization](https://wiki.apache.org/pig/PigMultiQueryPerformanceSpecification).

However, when you replace GROUP BY with FILTER, Pig will implicitly replace FILTER with SPLIT to do multi-query optimization, which will result in a single MR job.